# Использование Preference в RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня имеется RelativeLayout в котором есть пару кнопок и LinearLayout. Мне нужно, что бы по нажатию на кнопку в LinearLayout показывалась соответствующая xml разметка. Однако, в разметках нужны CheckBoxPreference. До этого в Preference дела не имел и не знаю как запихнуть такие CheckBox-ы и что написать в коде Java.
Сейчас в xml-ах разметка обычная с обычными CheckBox, мне нужно просто их "заменить" на CheckBoxPreference. А всё остальное уже готово. Так вот, как это сделать? Нужно ли весь RelativeLayout заменить на PreferenceScreen, или только xml разметки для LinearLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря для чего Вам это нужно:

- если нужен просто внешний вид как у `CheckBoxPreference` - то правильнее будет сделать стиль обычному чекбоксу;
- если они нужны именно как настройки - то описать в отдельном XML-файле в каталоге `res/xml/`, создать из него `PreferenceFragment`, а его уже добавить в `Activity`, так же как и обычный фрагмент.
  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#Fragment

Использовать `Preference` в обычной разметке нельзя.